# Choose Azure Table Partition Key base on row count or size

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, nosql

I'm designing a hashing algorithm that will generate partition keys for a azure table. I'm taking in account 2 scenarios:

1. Generate key based on row count
2. Generate key based on data size

Explaning: Imagine that i have 300 entities to insert (remember that this is a non relational stores so lets say that its, 10 costumers, 50 sales, 240 sales items)... to balance them, i will use 2 partitions keys: K1 and K2.
**In the "row count mode"** insert 1 will have K1, insert 2 will have k2, insert 3->K1, insert 4->k2 and so on... very straight forward and prob what most people do...
If **I use "data size"**, lets say that the first 50kb will get K1,51-100kb K2, 101-150 K1, 151-200 K2, which can lead to: insert 1, 2 and 3 using K1, insert 4 using K2, insert 5 using K1, insert 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 and 14 using K2...

My question is: when searching, which "tatics" will enable the optimum throughput?

**Edti1:**
What I am most worried here is the unbalance between the partitions and raw performance. Let's further expand and imagine that this is a multi-tenant app. If I choose `Tenant Id` as partition key i will have to work around the fact that as a tenant data becomes larger the query performance will drop more fast than if i had chosen a partition key such as `Tenant Id + Month of the Sale` because in the second scenario i would be able to run parallel queries such as "tenant1January", "tenant1February", "Tenant1Marchar"...

Comment: I think that the answer to this depends heavily on the business logic of your application. What types of reads will be performed most often? By what criteria can the records for those reads be found? Reads will be fastest when using PartitionKey + RowKey. Reads get much slower when scanning records by a field that is not one of those two keys. It can also depend on the number of records you have any how often you access them. For example, if you have maybe a few thousand records you might read them all by partitionkey and cache them locally.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, I'm going to go with neither.

The partition key is the most important thing to consider when designing your table storage query.  If I understand your PK schemes correctly then to get any piece of the information you're saving quickly, you'll need to know either how many other rows it was saved with, or the size of all of that other data.

I would take a step back and think about how you want to get this data out and then think about what PK and RK you want to use.